# How to join two large CSV files?

Tags: python, bash, csv, join, dataset

I have two large .csv files that I would like to join.

**file1.csv** has the following structure:

```
productcode; *many useless columns* ; startdate; enddate; *some other useless columns*
```

**file2.csv** has the following structure:

```
productcode; *many useless columns different from file1* ; page; startdate; enddate; *some othe useless columns*
```

I would like to join the two files into a file (let's say, `out.csv`) with the same structure as file1.csv **but** with the "page" column from file2.csv, i.e.

```
productcode; *useless columns* ; page; startdate; enddate; *useless columns*
```

The join conditions are same productcode and overlapping dates, i.e.:

```
file1.productcode == file2.productcode
```

and

```
!(file1.endate<file2.startdate or file2.enddate<file1.startdate)
```

However, I have no idea on how to do that. One possibility could be to export the two CSVs into MySql, process them and then export the result in a final CSV file. However, that takes time (and is resource consuming).

I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load them with pandas and use the function .join() to join both with the column reference you need

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I've found another way: I've written an AWK script (which I'm more familiar with), trasforming the dates in timestamps using mktime(). My main difficulty was in comparing the two dates.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem, you have the same function in python with date time and parse to help you in the conversion of timestamp format.